# get week for 01-01-2011 using strftime returns 00

Tags: php, strftime

```
$w = strftime("%W",mktime(0,0,0,1,1,2011));    
echo $w;
```

returns "00"

Why?

Answer (score 5):

The first Monday of 2011 is the 3rd, therefore the 1st and 2nd are in week 0.

Comment: No, because they're not in 2010.

Comment: It is part of the 52nd week of 2010, but they're not in 2010 so it rolls over to 0.

Comment: I understand the logic behind it. But I don't like it. There are people who work in week 52 day 6 and 7 ;-)